# Simplifying button that when clicked changes boolean value

Tags: elm

I've created a button that holds a boolean value and when you click it, it changes this value and text inside the button. The code below works but I have a feeling I'm doing an overkill. How can I write this button as simple as possible but still following the ELM architecture?

```
module BtnPin where

import Html exposing ( Html )
import Html.Events as E
import StartApp.Simple as StartApp

-- MAIN

main =
  StartApp.start { model = emptyModel, view = view, update = update }

-- MODEL

type alias Model =
    {pinned : Bool}

init : Model
init = Model False

emptyModel : Model
emptyModel =
    { pinned = False
    }

pin : Model -> Model
pin model =
    if model.pinned then
        Model False
    else
        Model True

viewPin : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html
viewPin address model =
    if model.pinned == True then
        Html.button
            [ E.onClick address Pin ]
            [ Html.text <| "Unpin" ]
    else
        Html.button
            [ E.onClick address Pin ]
            [ Html.text <| "Pin" ]

-- UPDATE

type Action = Pin 

update : Action -> Model -> Model
update action model =
  pin model 

-- VIEW

view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html
view address model =
    Html.div []
    [ viewPin address model ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more explicit you are, and the closer you stay to the Elm Architecture, the easier it is to read for someone who knows the pattern. It's also easy to extend. But of course you can simplify a component that you don't expect to change.

Just remember that with the code you have in your question, the only documentation you need is the one-sentence description, because the code is Elm Architecture, everything has type annotations and is super simple. When you condense your code, you may need more documentation.

A simplified button:

```
module BtnPin where

import Html exposing ( Html )
import Html.Events as E
import StartApp.Simple as StartApp

main =
  StartApp.start { model = False, view = view, update = always not }

-- VIEW

view : Signal.Address () -> Bool -> Html
view address model =
  Html.div [] [ viewPin address model ]

viewPin : Signal.Address () -> Bool -> Html
viewPin address model =
  let
    text = if model then "Unpin" else "Pin"
  in
    Html.button
      [ E.onClick address () ]
      [ Html.text text ]
```

This may be a bit extreme, so you can compromise by defining an `update` function, a `Model` type and an `Action` type. But then you're pretty close to where you started...

Comment: Thank you, I'm confused about addresses, even in my own code. Do you know any good documentation on how to work with addresses? Like what address comes in `view address model` when you run the program?

Comment: Take a look at the source code for StartApp.Simple. There are only a few lines of code. 

In short, StartApp creates a Signal.mailbox and `Signal.foldp` over the mailbox.signal. That mailbox's address is being sent to the view.